# Magento 2.1.3 : URL key For Specified Store Already Exists When Saving Categories

Tags: magento-2.1.3, bug

I searched for this kind of issue and saw many others experiencing this thing like me. I tried those fixes that they recommend but it's not working on my end.

Maybe you guys can suggest what is the best thing or any recommendations how to fix this one.

[image]

Any ideas on the best solution to fix this bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Truncating your `url_rewrite` table & run re-indexing.

It will create all url-key's automatically.

**=> Note : Take backup of that table before truncate it.**

For regenerate url :

Download this [module](https://github.com/Iazel/magento2-regenurl) and copy the Iazel directory into app/code/

Then you can regenerate SEO Friendly URL's for catalog/products via Console

```
# Regenerate url for all products and the global store
php bin/magento iazel:regenurl

# Regenerate url for products with id (1, 2, 3, 4) for store 1
php bin/magento iazel:regenurl -s1 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Hmmm, I saw this method before. Thanks also I will try this one.

Comment: Hello @Emipro Thanks, for now, this one solves my problem.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: But there's a problem, I noticed the product's url changed to this kind of format: catalog/product/view/id/4513/s/test/

Comment: Any ideas about this one?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: How about the categories? The categories also has the same type of url format just like I told you earlier.

Comment: https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites --- How about this one have you tried this before?

Comment: You can use this. I used that iazel extension.

Comment: Is iazel Capable of regenerating the Category Url Also?

Answer (score 0):

That's known issue in `Magento2.1.x`

this issue is solved now `magento2.2`

you can check here for more detail

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7298

for quick hack you can do following

Create a prefrence of this class `vendor/magento/module-url-rewrite/Model/Storage/DbStorage.php`

and rewrite `doReplace()` this method

```
protected function doReplace($urls)
{
    foreach ($this->createFilterDataBasedOnUrls($urls) as $type => $urlData) {
    $urlData[UrlRewrite::ENTITY_TYPE] = $type;
    $this->deleteByData($urlData);
    }
    $data = [];
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $data[] = $url->toArray();
    }

     /* Add this line : Get rid of rewrite for root Magento category to unduplicate things*/
    foreach($data as $key =>$info){
        if(isset($info['target_path']) && stristr($info['target_path'],'/category/1') && $info['entity_type']=='product'){
                unset($data[$key]);
        }
    }

    $this->insertMultiple($data);
}
```

Comment: I tried your method but unfortunately, it's not working on my end. Thanks anyway.